# Enzyme switch case with react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, enzyme

I've got a function that depends on parameters return components or null. I created an array of objects with parameters and component that should be returned. How to check what I return with switch/case statement.

```
export const getMiConfiguration = miConfigurationType => {
    switch (miConfigurationType) {
        case MiConfigurationTypes.WanderingDetection :
        case MiConfigurationTypes.MuteWanderingDetection:
            return <WanderingDetection />

        case MiConfigurationTypes.OpenWanderingControl :
        case MiConfigurationTypes.LockedWanderingControl:
            return <WanderingControl />

        default:
            return null
    }
}
```

Test

```
describe.only('getMiConfiguration', () => {

    ;[{id: MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly, component: null},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.WanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.MuteWanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.LockedWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.OpenWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
    ].forEach(({id, component}) =>
        it('should render correct component', () => {
            const result = getMiConfiguration(id)
        }))
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

This helps me, but still have issue with testing redux form

```
describe('getMiConfiguration', () => {
    ;[{id: MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly, component: null},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.WanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.MuteWanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.LockedWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.OpenWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
    ].forEach(({id, component}) =>
        it(`should render correct ${component} component for ${id} type`, () => {
            const result = getMiConfiguration(id)

            if (component === null)
                expect(result).to.be.null
            else
                result.type.should.be.equal(component.type)
        }))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract `it` method from the loop, like:

```
describe.only('getMiConfiguration', () => {
    it('should render correct component', () => {
        [
            {id: MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly, component: null},
            {id: MiConfigurationTypes.WanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
            {id: MiConfigurationTypes.MuteWanderingDetection, component: <WanderingDetection/>},
            {id: MiConfigurationTypes.LockedWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
            {id: MiConfigurationTypes.OpenWanderingControl, component: <WanderingControl/>},
        ].forEach(({id, component}) => {
            const result = getMiConfiguration(id);
            // your assertion
            expect(result).toBe('your expected value');
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: toBe use for true or false statment, I need to check the null when MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly